# put array values in multiple variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know I can put item by item to variable like:

```
var array = [15,20];
var a = array[0];
var b = array[1];
```

But I curious how to put array values in multi variable in one line like `list()` in `php`:

```
list($a,$b) = [15,20]; // $a = 15, $b = 20
```

Is it possible or not ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript's array de-structuring syntax,

```
var array = [15,20];
const [x, y] = array;
```

Comment: very good, thanks, Its better to set `var` instead of `const` to can change later

Comment: @ttrasn No, `const` is better because you should always avoid needing to reassign a variable. But if you need to, you should use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Keep in mind this a relatively new JavaScript feature. All relevant, current browsers support it, but for example Internet Explorer (11 and before) does not. See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_destructuring

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [Destructuring assignment - Javascript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment)

```js
matches = ['12', 'watt'];
[value, unit] = matches;
console.log(value,unit)
```